# How to access an httpOnly cookie on a NodeJs server inside a redux action?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, reactjs, jwt

So, I am starting to build a fully universal/isomorphic React/Redux project. Login state is maintained via JWTs.

The client accesses the JWT via localStorage, but I also want to set an httpOnly cookie that contains the JWT, so that the server can see it and render pages appropriately.

What's the best way to set and access httpOnly cookies with Redux actions? It's relatively easy with express, but I want to wrap these things inside redux actions and share a common store between the server/client, so I am at a bit of a loss.

I did see [redux-effects-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-effects-cookie), has anyone used this?